# How to move pandas table to the middle of the notebook?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I currently have a pandas table (type is pandas.Styler) and I want to move the table to the middle of the jupyter notebook so when I convert it to html. The table should be aligned center of the report.

Comment: Hello, can you attach code or  images to your message to help us understand your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.